# how not to preload the image in html content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 3 tabs by using the [jQuery ui tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#default) there is only one tab that can be viewed in the beginning. that is why I think most of the visitors will not bother and open the other two tabs. so my question is, how can you prevent the browser from loading the images only? and only load them when their specific tab is clicked on.

Comment: Just create a "click" event for the tab and only set the "src" property when the click event fires.

Comment: @rontornambe do you have a demonstration of how can this be done?

Comment: post the html and jQuery

Comment: @Jai just click on the jquery ui tabs link in my question. My code is pretty much the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choice to accomplish your goal.

1. Set url in your tab and put the content to other pages. Then jQuery
   UI will load the content by ajax when user clicks on the tab. See [jQuery UI ajax doc](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax).
2. You can use some tricks to load your images. The trick is set the image src when the panel is actived. At the beginning, put the src as presrc attribute, when the tab is activating, copy presrc and set it to src.

Code example on jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/4WYCC/1/

HTML

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Test tab</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <img presrc="https://www.google.com.hk/logos/2013/miriam_makebas_81st_birthday-1417005-hp.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
  $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
      beforeActivate: function( event, ui ) {
          $("img",ui.newPanel).each(function(){
              if(!this.src)
              {
                  this.src = $(this).attr("presrc");
              }
          });
      }
  });
});
```

Although the trick in second choice is work, I will recommend to use the first choice.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery UI allows you to use URLs for your tabs, their content will only be loaded when clicked. See the [docs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax)

Answer (score 1):

This answer provides an alternative to @user1737909's solution. As alluded to, a new HTML page with your tab content can be created and retrieved only when the tab is pressed. An alternative to creating a new page follows:

HTML associated with tab2:

```
  <div id="tabs-2">
     <img id="img2" src="" alt="image description" />
  </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#tabs').bind('tabsselect', function (event, ui) {
  switch (ui.index) { //index=1 is tab-2
    case 1:
       $("#img2").attr("src","link2image2");
    case 2:
       $("#img3").attr("src","link2image3");
  ...
  }

});
```

HTH